# show custom pop-up message when session expired

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, typescript

I need to show a custom pop-up message when session expired using MVC4, AngularJS and typescript. I have a session attribute below:

```
public class UserSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {
            var controller = ((BaseApiController)filterContext.ControllerContext.Controller);

            var userInfo = controller.SessionState.Get<UserSessionInfo>("UserSessionInfo");

            if (userInfo == null)
            {
               // throw new HttpException(401, "Session Expired");
            }

            controller.UserSessionInfo = userInfo;

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

And use it in the method for eg:

```
[UserSession]
public Person EditPerson(Person person)
{
}
```

Now, when session expired I want to show a custom pop-up with a Refresh button.

Any idea how to implement this? I saw this one but need more info `http://forums.asp.net/t/1630594.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to implement this?

You can handle the error `401 / Session Expired` via a `catch` added to the `$http.get`/`put`/`post`/`delete`. All of the these return a promise.

[More on `.catch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Hi @basarat- can you please give me a sample implementation that you've suggested?